# run an application with "phar" extension

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, phar

I have no experience in PHP, and I need to launch a file with "phar" extension. I read a lot of information abot this but without any result. I installed php, but dont understand how to run phar file.

Comment: did you try `php filename.phar`  ? (in console)

Comment: Yes, I fulfilled this. Thanks a lot. 
The problem was with environment variables